# c# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Tags: c#

I have a code written some time ago that worked:

```
IHTMLDocument3 doc3 = (IHTMLDocument3)doc;
            IHTMLDocument7 doc7 = (IHTMLDocument7)doc;

            IHTMLElementCollection elc;
            IHTMLElement el;
            IHTMLElement chld;
            IHTMLDOMNode dn;

if ((chld = el.children[1].children[0].children[1]) != null
                && chld.tagName == "A"
                )
```

Now C# (express 2008, .NET 3.5) complains that
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

referring to el.children[1]....

What would be the problem? I know that worked before.
Thanks for any clues,

UPDATE:
I just tested in VS2012 and works, compiles and run just fine.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IHTMLElement test = null;

    IHTMLElement xxx = test.children[1];

}
```

CONFIRMED:
The same code in VS2008 is not working. The only difference is that I had to re-generate mshtml.dll for each project, by using different VS command prompts (each for .NET version).

Generation was done with the same command:

```
sn -k mykey.snk
tlbimp.exe /out:mshtml.dll /keyfile:mykey.snk mshtml.tlb
```

I really don't understand... any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: We would need to see the code for the `IHTMLElement` class and the code for the type of property or public variable `children`

Comment: IHTMLElement is standard from mshtml, re-generated for IE11, I've done before and seems to be ok. Children is DOM node children, also microsoft standard, used as is.

Comment: `children` -> `Children`. Shouldn't it be an uppercase `C`?

Comment: Is that a compiler or a runtime message? (Not all documents are created alike..)

Comment: it's lower case (I cannot post image). It's a design time error, like IHTMLElement would have other structure

Comment: I noticed in my old projects I used C# 2012 and now I try with 2008 express, both 3.5 framework

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no  **collection**  property  named **children** in the interface `IHtmlElement`, please check IHtmlElement properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) I think you can use `All` or `Children` property instead.

Comment: I swear it worked :) I know that mshtml.dll can be the problem but I follow the same steps to re-create (the one included default in windows is for .NET 1 or so). I had to re-create for IHTMLDocument7 like elements